# Expected latency while streaming audio with Bluetooth LE

Tags: bluetooth, streaming, bluetooth-lowenergy, audio-streaming, latency

I'm posting for the first time in this forum and English is not my first language so sorry for any mistakes ;) .

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to live stream audio using Bluetooth LE 4.X technology maintaining a very low latency. Namely below 10 ms. I'm trying to live stream a music instrument via bluetooth and the difference between the instant the instrument is played and the musician hears it should be negligible.

I'm asking in particular for the BLE because of what i saw in this page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy.
In the technical specifications it says: Latency (from a non-connected state) 6 ms. but i cant find where that value came from and even so i don't know if that is the value that I'm looking for.

Thanks! :)

Comment: your best bet is to use Classic BT with A2DP profile. A2DP supports multiple codecs namely SBC, APTX, MP3 etc. APTX seems to have the least latency due to smaller block size as compared to SBC. note that 48Khz sterio music requires 345Kb/s and LE's theoretical maximum at GATT level is less than that. please see http://soundexpert.org/news/-/blogs/bluetooth-audio-quality-a2dp. if you really need LE, then you might require bluetooth 5.0 (4x speed) + custom profiles which implements some streaming protocol ( such as MTP)

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer is very useful. In relation to the sampling frequency i'm planing on using a lower value. Maybe 44khz or less. The LE is not a condition.

Answer (score 0):

BLE is specifically for sending small amounts of data with an emphasis on saving power by sacrificing speed.  If you're concerned about speed and latency then you probably shouldn't be using BLE.

To answer your question, though, the latency is dependent on the connection interval.  The connection interval is how long the two devices wait between transfers of data.

The 6ms the wikipedia page is talking about the length of time it takes to do the initial connection between the two devices (BLE is faster at making initial connections than "classic" Bluetooth because I think they made it simpler), but that isn't related to the latency during the regular usage after the connection is established.

Most Bluetooth 4.0 devices that support BLE also support regular Bluetooth, so I'd suggest using that if at all possible (since your concern is latency and not power consumption).

Comment: Thanks! i thought that i was reading the wrong data. i'll look into it.